# Polyhedron with $11$ faces

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solid-geometry

Show that there is no polyhedron with exactly $11$ faces such that each face is a polygon having an odd number of sides.

Comment: How much edges would it have ?

Comment: It may have any number of edges.

Comment: Lierre was giving you a hint.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Twice the number of edges of a polyhedron is the sum of the number of sides of each face. If you have $11$ faces and each face has an odd number of sides, the sum of the number of sides of the faces is odd. Twice the number of edges is even. Contradiction.